# Lead ListView SOQL query with CampaignMember.Status fails through REST API

Tags: soql, rest-api, leads, list-view, campaign-member

I'm trying to retrieve results from a Lead List View SOQL query via the REST API and found that the API always fails when the List View includes references to `CampaignMember.Status`. Based on the documentation around 1 to 1 relationships like Leads and CampaignMembers, it seems like the query should work.

As an example, I created a List View using options available in the UI and that shows results in both Salesforce Lightning and Classic, but when I attempt to use the rest API, it throws an error.

I use this call to retrieve the query:

```
https://na124.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Lead/listviews/${LIST_VIEW_ID}/describe
```

Receive this query back:

```
SELECT Name, Email, toLabel(CampaignMember.Status), Id, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp 
  FROM Lead USING SCOPE mine 
  WHERE IsConverted = false 
    AND Id IN (SELECT LeadId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId = 'CAMPAIGN_ID') 
    AND CampaignMember.Status = 'Sent' 
  ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST, Id ASC NULLS FIRST
```

When I attempt to retrieve results directly using `https://na124.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Lead/listviews/${LIST_VIEW_ID}/results` or by using the above SOQL query, I get the following error:

```
INVALID_FIELD: 
SELECT Name, Email, toLabel(CampaignMember.Status), Id, CreatedDate
                            ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:29
Didn't understand relationship 'CampaignMember' in field path. If you are attempting to use a
custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please 
reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Is this a difference in what's supported in the Salesforce UI directly vs the API, or is there some way I need to change the queries? I've tested this in Salesforce `v39.0` through `v51.0`

Comment: As far as I can see, Lead is a parent of CampaignMember... so maybe that's some internal relationship that us plebs can't use?

Comment: Yeah, that's what's confusing to me. It seems like the API _should_ return valid queries, right?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is highly suspicious, but I do see in the SOQL docs that `toLabel` cannot be used with the `ORDER BY` clause in your query. Would it be possible to remove that clause and see if the same error message is returned?

Here is the [relevant excerpt from the SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_tolabel.htm):

```
The toLabel() method cannot be used with the ORDER BY Clause. Salesforce always uses the order defined in the picklist, just like reports
```

Comment: Great point - removing that clause triggers the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

An executable query would be:

```
SELECT Name, Email,  Id, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp 
  FROM Lead USING SCOPE mine 
  WHERE IsConverted = false 
    AND Id IN 
      (SELECT LeadId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId = 'CAMPAIGN_ID' 
              AND Status = 'Sent') 
     
  ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST, Id ASC NULLS FIRST
```

There is no lookup field from `Lead` to `CampaignMember` - CampaignMember is a junction between `Lead` and `Campaign`

So, the clause `Status = 'Sent'` needs to be in the join filter, not the outer filter. Thus, you can't use `toLabel(CampaignMember.Status)` in the outer query

A different way to write this query would be:

```
SELECT LeadId, Lead.Email, toLabel(Status) 
  FROM CampaignMember 
  WHERE CampaignId = 'CAMPAIGNID'
    AND Lead.OwnerId = 'SomeUserRecordId'
```

Now I appreciate you are trying to do a REST Lead `List View` query but the query you get back is unexecutable

Comment: Thanks for the detail here. This was the direction I was leaning. I think what's confusing to me is why the Salesforce API would return a query that can't be executed?

Comment: I surmise it is because the list view you can construct on Lead is convenient for application needs but underneath, before rendering the result, SFDC is essentially doing what I answered; the REST API doesn't know that.  99% of listviews are queries on an object and its fields (no relationships) - but for Lead and certain other objects, SFDC provides "convenience" list views/fields that traverse relationships behind-the-scenes